# Multiple classes with same styling with specific attributes to each class in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

Assume the following code:

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="class-1">Class 1</div>
  <div class="class-2">Class 2</div>
  <div class="class-3">Class 3</div>
  <div class="class-4">Class 4</div>
  <div class="class-5">Class 5</div>
</div>
```

```css
/* Code every class shares */
.example .class-1,
.example .class-2,
.example .class-3,
.example .class-4,
.example .class-5 {
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    /* More code... */
}

/* Code that is different */
.example .class-1 {
    color: red;
}

.example .class-2 {
    color: blue;
}

.example .class-3 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.example .class-4 {
    background-color: darkcyan;
}

.example .class-5 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating yourself using SCSS? Please keep in mind that I am not looking for a way to iterate through a map with the attributes.

Comment: What have you tried in SCSS? You still need to define the styles in SCSS - since it compiles to CSS. `.example { &::before, &::after { content: Hello World; color: red } &::after { color: blue } }`

Comment: @disinfor 's example is an example of nesting, one of the best improvements Sass makes to CSS.  You can also leverage loops and variables-- however, this won't apply universally, as sometimes it is minimally DRYer and much harder to read.  What exactly are you trying to shorten/collapse?

Comment: @disinfor Similiar to you, I did `.example { &::before, &::after { content: "Hello World!" } &::before { color: red; } &::after { color: blue; } }`. However this can become quite messy if you have more than two classes that have to refer to the same style, while other classes have to have unique attributes.

Comment: @AlexanderNied What I am trying to achieve is a way to not be unnecessarily redundant. Imagine a styling with multiple classes. The & currently will refer to every single one of them. Similiar to JS, `&[1]` could refer the first class **only**, but it's obviously not valid code.

Comment: You need to clarify your original question with your comment about multiple classes. However, what situation makes it "messy"? Add your SCSS that you think is "messy" - or an example. We can't really read your mind and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @disinfor I have provided a more exaggerated example in my original post.

Comment: Is that really the naming convention, e.g class-1, class-2? Or is it really different class names? You could really simplify this, however, you will never avoid the different section. You need to define those selectors. No way around that.

Comment: I am looking for a way to simplify the selectors, so that I do not have to write class-1 multiple times, for example. `.example .class-1, .example . class-2 { /* ... */ }` should also be possible, however I would repeat myself a lot if I had to do that. Imagine like a :nth-child() for the & seperated by commas. FYI class-1, class-2, etc. is just an example. It could be anything.

Comment: @ThaumicTom added an answer that may help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, this is something I can think of in order to not repeat yourself too much using SCSS

```
.example {
    /* Code every class shares */
    [class^="class-"] {
       padding: 1em;
       font-family: sans-serif;
       /* More code... */
    }

    /* Code that is different */
    .class-1 {
        color: red;
    }

    .class-2 {
        color: blue;
    }

    .class-3 {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .class-4 {
        background-color: darkcyan;
    }

    .class-5 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `[class^="class-"]` will affect all elements which contain classes that starts with "class-" like `class-a`, `class-x`, etc
More details about attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: This is really unfortunate that SCSS barely makes a difference in here, but it is the only way of doing so. In any case, `[class^="class-"]` won't work in every situation, but it is defintily better than my initial thought of using a `@for` loop. However, I will mark it as solution, as it doesn't get better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of what you could do with the **provided** example code:

```
/* Code every class shares */
.example > div {
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    /* More code... */
    
    &.class {
        &-1 {
            color: red;
        }
        
        &-2 {
            color: blue;
        }
        
        &-3 {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        &-4 {
            background-color: darkcyan;
        }
        
        &-5 {
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    }
}
```

That compiles to this:

```
/* Code every class shares */
.example > div {
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* More code... */
}
.example > div.class-1 {
  color: red;
}
.example > div.class-2 {
  color: blue;
}
.example > div.class-3 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.example > div.class-4 {
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
.example > div.class-5 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Because you are changing different properties for each `.class-*` element, you cannot avoid writing it out like this, unless you want to get into [SASS Maps](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps), which may work for you if you want to pre-define styles.

```
$elements : ( 
    1: ( 'color' : 'red', 'text-align' : 'left', 'font-size': '16px'), 
    2: ( 'color' : 'blue'), 
    3: ( 'font-weight' : 'bold')
    );


/* Code every class shares */
.example > div {
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    /* More code... */
    
    &.class {
        @each $index, $maps in $elements {
            &-#{$index} {
                @each $prop, $style in $maps {
                    #{$prop} : #{$style}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
/* Code every class shares */
.example > div {
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* More code... */
}
.example > div.class-1 {
  color: red;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.example > div.class-2 {
  color: blue;
}
.example > div.class-3 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: While this solution is more explicit than Diego's answer, it is essentially the same thing. The usage of SASS maps is handy, but it wouldn't work if there were multiple attributes.

Comment: @ThaumicTom  I did not see Diego's since I was writing this. What do you mean `multiple attributes`? If you mean properties for each element, see my edit.

Comment: Properties. That's what I meant. However, this does not necessarily improve readability much, as well as it looks like a big unnecessary hack.

Comment: Sure. I'm just giving you ways to do it since you asked for less redundancy. SASS maps aren't a hack and are quite useful even in this situation, since you could house all of your selector properties above the main selector nesting. And if you need to make a change, you don't have to scroll through a large nest, you could make the update in the map. Anyway, good luck!